# `(long)(float)Long.MAX_VALUE` has the exact value, how is that possible?

Tags: java, casting, floating-point, precision

`Long` has more bytes than `Float`, so I expected that the highest long might not be stored exactly in a float. This is indeed the case:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%d", Long.MAX_VALUE));
// 9223372036854775807
System.out.println(String.format("%.0f", (float)Long.MAX_VALUE));
// 9223372036854776000
```

*BUT* if I convert this float back to a long, how is it possible that I get the original value back?

```
System.out.println(String.format("%d", (long)(float)Long.MAX_VALUE));
// 9223372036854775807
```

How did Java somehow recover my lost precision?

*EDIT 1*: some extra info:

```
float j = Long.MAX_VALUE;
System.out.println((long)j);
// 9223372036854775807
```

So even if the value is stored, the effect is the same. Is Java really ignoring the 'cast' even if it's stored? I feel that it shouldn't do that; it changes the result.

*EDIT 2 (was wrong, undone)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because the result of `(float)Long.MAX_VALUE` is outside the range of `long`.  So when it's converted back, it's clamped to the maximum representable value.

From the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) (emphasis mine):

> A narrowing conversion of a floating-point number to an integral type T takes two steps:
>
> [...]
>
> Otherwise, one of the following two cases must be true:
>
> [...]
>
> The value must be too large (a positive value of large magnitude or positive infinity), and the result of the first step is the **largest representable value** of type int or long.

To prove it:

```
long x = Long.MAX_VALUE - 10;
System.out.println(x);                // 9223372036854775797
System.out.printf("%.0f", (float)x);  // 9223372036854776000
System.out.println((long)(float)x);   // 9223372036854775807 (look familiar?)
```

(Thanks to @T.J. Crowder for the suggested example.)

Comment: Brilliant. (And verified via the simple expedient of using `Long.MAX_VALUE - 10`). Which explains the second example. In the first (`System.out.println(String.format("%d", (long)(float)Long.MAX_VALUE));`), the cast is just completely ignored.